# how to stop propagation after making an ajax request in angularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have an ajax request to server side script in order to validate my captcha. I want my requested script to stopPropagation based on server response.

this is my script:

```
$scope.submit = function(e){    
    s_registration.captchaValidation($scope.txtCaptcha)
        .then(function(r){
            if(r == 'failed'){
              e.stopPropagation();
            }       
    });
}
```

I understand this not gonna work because the response will not arrive soon due to ajax call, but i cannot find another way that fix my scenario. Any advice guys?

Comment: Do you want to validate captcha first then submit ?

Comment: @MohanSingh yes. Actually I split the form into 5 part using bootstrap tabs, each part has a button. i use stopPropagation on each button to validate user input before move on to the next part. The validation itself is client side except for this captcha. This captcha appears on step 4, so when user click on the button it should validate first (server side), if its pass then the button would take the user to the 5th part.

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop propagation synchronously, and you called it asynchronously

```
$scope.submit = function(e){    
    s_registration.captchaValidation($scope.txtCaptcha);
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```